# Gracefully serve MP4 from Apache or Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, video, streaming, mp4, apache2.4

I've looked a bit and seen a number of questions related to serving mp4, but I have not yet seen an answer to "How can I serve MP4 from Wordpress and/or Apache?" I believe it is possible as the twentyseventeen theme IIRC lets you host your own.

I am looking to host my own, if possible, after [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/102974/how-to-remove-the-related-videos-at-end-of-youtube-embedded-video) had an anchor linking to [this blog post](https://www.maxlaumeister.com/blog/hide-related-videos-in-youtube-embeds/), and the custom generated minimized code did not work on [this page on my site](https://cjshayward.com/last-lecture/). Both that and the present homepage have the offered HTML solution but fail to do what is intended, namely hide related offerings like the (now retired) `rel=0` parameter.

What, if any, options do I have to serve MP4 gracefully, with or without streaming, from Wordpress under Apache? I would ideally like something as graceful as under Youtube, but without related videos.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You definitively want to peek a look at the [Plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/mp4/) WordPress offers for video streaming. For example, [Easy Video Player](https://noorsplugin.com/wordpress-video-plugin/) allows you to *"embed both self-hosted videos or videos that are externally hosted using direct links"*.

It's just a one-liner. Can't get simpler than that:

```
[evp_embed_video url="http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/videos/myvid.mp4"]
```

As of functionality, it will work in Apache, since the webserver only transfers the video by HTTP and the playing occurs in the client side with HTML5. However, you must check that your hosting gives you enough bandwidth to stream content to all your visitors

Answer (score 0):

By default, [Wordpress provides a [video] shortcode](https://wordpress.org/support/article/video-shortcode/). I'm trying to see if that will work, as a matter of using Wordpress default functionality.